# ASP.NET Wizard Control DropDownlist SelectedIndexChanged Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

Current I'm building a wizard control for data entry entry purposes, where the steps need to be build dynamically based on the items selected in a checkbox list on the first step. I'm building the wizard and it's controls dynamically in the OnInit method like so:

```
WizardStep initiationStep = new WizardStep() { Title = "Add New Account/Service", ID = IniationStep" };
AddContentToInitiationStep(initiationStep);

WizardStep drugAndAlcoholStep = new WizardStep() { Title = "Drug and Alcohol", ID = "DrugAndAlcStep" };
BuildDrugAndAlcoholWizardStep(drugAndAlcoholStep);

WizardStep omrtStep = new WizardStep() { Title = "OMRT", ID = "OMRTStep" };
BuildOMRTWizardStep(omrtStep);
```

The steps are loaded up front, and I'm using jQuery to hide them in the side bar based on what the user selects in the checkbox list. The problem is in the BuildDrugAndAlcoholWizardStep method. In that method, I'm using a custom server control to build a dynamically loaded repeater.

```
private void BuildDrugAndAlcoholWizardStep(WizardStep step)
{
    AdvTable drugAndAlcoholTable = new AdvTable(0, 5);

    DataTable dt = ClientRegistrationServicesDB.ClientRegistrationServices_LoadByPolicyTemplateId(Config.GetDefaultDataStore(), policyTemplateId);

    var lblCollections = new Label() { Text = "Will this client use Consolidated Billing or will they pay the site directly?", CssClass = "label_l1" };
    AdvRadioButtonList radioBtnList = new AdvRadioButtonList() { ID = "BillType" };
    radioBtnList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Consolidated Billing", "ConsolidatedBilling"));
    radioBtnList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Pay Site Directly", "PaySiteDirectly"));

    AdvTabledRepeaterClientRegistrationDrugAndAlcohol mDrugAndAlc = new AdvTabledRepeaterClientRegistrationDrugAndAlcohol();

    drugAndAlcoholTable[0, 0].Controls.Add(lblCollections);
    drugAndAlcoholTable[1, 0].Controls.Add(radioBtnList);
    drugAndAlcoholTable[2, 0].Controls.Add(AdvQuickLiterals.BR);
    drugAndAlcoholTable[3, 0].Controls.Add(mDrugAndAlc);

    step.Controls.Add(drugAndAlcoholTable);
}
```

In the actual repeater server control, we have an overridden CreateChildControls method that adds the actual controls to the repeater:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();

    this.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    this.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    this.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    this.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    this.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    this.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    this.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    this.Cells.Add(new TableCell());

    this.Cells[0].Controls.Add(mPolicyTemplates);
    this.Cells[1].Controls.Add(DrugPrice);
    this.Cells[2].Controls.Add(AlcoholFee);
    this.Cells[3].Controls.Add(MemberSetupFee);
    this.Cells[4].Controls.Add(AnnualMaintenanceFee);
    this.Cells[5].Controls.Add(RandomRate);
    this.Cells[6].Controls.Add(TestPanel);
    this.Cells[7].Controls.Add(StartDate);

    mPolicyTemplates.ID = "PolicyTemplates";
    DrugPrice.ID = "DrugPrice";
    AlcoholFee.ID = "AlcoholFee";
    MemberSetupFee.ID = "MemberSetupFee";
    AnnualMaintenanceFee.ID = "AnnualMaintenanceFee";
    RandomRate.ID = "RandomRate";
    TestPanel.ID = "TestPanel";
    StartDate.ID = "StartDate";

    mPolicyTemplates.AutoPostBack = true;
    mPolicyTemplates.SelectedIndexChanged += PolicyTemplates_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```

The issue is with the mPolicyTemplates drop down. There's an "Add New Row" link on the repeater that causes a new row to be added for data entry. In that row is a drop down for the policy template, and when a policy template is selected in the drop down, the row it was selected in is supposed to populate with data from a database call in the SelectedIndexChanged method, the only problem is it's not firing. A post back is made to the page, and the server controls data is lost as well as the new row that was supposed to be added. The Init and Load methods are hit in the actual page, but no events are fired in the server control.

I've tried placing the AutoPostBack and SelectedIndexChanged initializers in the OnInit, OnLoad, and OnDataBinding events in the server control, but the event never fires.

Am I supposed to set the SelectedIndex changed event in another method in the Life Cycle? Is there something I need to do on the page itself so when the drop down is selected, the correct values are loaded into the new row that is to be inserted?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried elevating the code from within `protected override void CreateChildControls()` to the init method of the repeater - I believe that may help.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but it's still not working even when moving the CreateChildControls code to the Init method of the repeater.

Comment: OK so I think `AdvTabledRepeaterClientRegistrationDrugAndAlcohol mDrugAndAlc = new AdvTabledRepeaterClientRegistrationDrugAndAlcohol();`
 needs an ID associating with it - keep the controls generation in the repeater init and add an ID for that item and give it a try.

Comment: Tried that as well and it's still not reaching the event handler in the repeater. Could it be something with how the wizard control is being generating?

Since users need to go back to any step, and have the data still there, I'm loading the wizard information on every postback in the OnInit method in the page. Is this correct to do?

Comment: When is `mPolicyTemplates` initialised - perhaps its adding the event handler and then being reinstantiated somewhere - does `mPolicyTemplates` get stored in viewstate at any point?

Comment: The mPolicyTemplates Drop Down List is a global level variable which is initialized in the OnInit method. The Event Handler is initialized in the OnInit method as well. I've tried initializing the Event Handler in other methods (OnDataBinding, OnLoad, OnPreRender) to no avail. The control is not stored in viewstate.

Comment: Thanks for you help on this, but I took out the built in wizard control and used enums to control the wizard state by hiding/showing controls on the paged based on the wizard enum saved in ViewState when navigation buttons are clicked (the page posts back to itself). The wizard is working as it should now.

Perhaps if I had more time to get the wizard control working, I could've figured it out, but with the way our application is architected (all HTML, Controls, etc. are built in the code behind), the Page Lifecycle was killing me.

Thanks again for your help.